# Collect set of unique elements in BigQuery materialized view

Tags: google-bigquery, materialized-views

I want to have an incremental materialized view which will group the data by some field and have a set (list of unique values) in another field.

This can be achieved with something like that

```
SELECT
  field1,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT field2) AS field2_set,
FROM
  table1
GROUP BY
  field1
```

But BigQuery complains about it with

> Incremental materialized views do not support the DISTINCT clause for aggregation function 'array_agg'

I understand why `COUNT DISTINCT` is not supported in incremental materialized views - there is no "context" to accumulate unique values, but for `ARRAY_AGG` the result array itself has all values, so seems it should be possible to guarantee uniqueness and have `ARRAY_AGG DISTINCT` even for incremental materialized views.

Are there any nice solutions for this problem, or the best one is the feature request to BigQuery team? (or maybe I was wrong in my reasoning and it's absolutely not possible with incremental materialized views)

Comment: Feature request in the BigQuery issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/325425525